# I cloned a git, how to make it live?

Tags: php, github, vagrant, vagrant-provision

im very frustrated because i lost a lot of hours reading and testing, and could not find how to make it live.
I cloned and downloaded Zidisha git
Then i followed these instruction: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCE93.png)
At the stage 5. -vagrant up  calls a file that doesn't have on the server.

[image]

I need to find a server with this saucy.box or exists a easier/another method?

Thank you

Comment: Is there another server or another box that do the same as this one?

    ==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
    ==> default: Adding box 'saucy-64' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/saucy/current/saucy-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box
    An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
    message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
    again.

    The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project is using ubuntu-saucy which has been deprecated (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Table_of_versions) so the link referenced on cloud-images is not available anymore, and the box itself (larryli/saucy64) is not available on vagrant atlas.

You are left with 2 options:

1. build your vagrant box yourself using the same ubuntu release (can be found https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/13.10/)
2. upgrade the ubuntu release to a more recent one and still supported (you can use trusty64 or xenial64)

Note: this project has not been updated for the last 3 years - there are many chances that you will find a lot of obsolete things in it.

Comment: Thanks you :) for your support